# Conditional styling of an element

Tags: css

I am trying to apply a style to a specific element ie. elements with a value of Priority 1 should be red and Priority 3 should be green

[image]

Is there a way for me to apply a conditional styling in css? I cannot change the html or alter it.

here is the css code:

```
.priorityDerived_shortCodeCell{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EC1818 !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the markup also for priority 2 and 3: does the markup change? What's the purpose of `idx` attribute? Is it related to the priority?

Comment: "Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example."

Comment: If we have to retype your code manually just so we can test it, nobody will help you. Don't post screenshots.

Comment: Presuming the `idx` attribute contains the priority value, this could be used in your CSS selector: `.priorityDerived_shortCodeCell[idx="1"]`

Comment: @ecolema I like your solution and I tried it but it doesn't work. Are there any other ways that you can think of to make it work?

Comment: Use javaScript to add class names to each element with 'idx' attribute:
`$('[idx]').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('idx_' + $(this).attr('idx'));  
});`

CSS: `.idx_1 {}` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily you could use this:

```
<style>.red { color: red; }</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>PRIORITY1</td>
        <td>PRIORITY2</td>
        <td>PRIORITY3</td>
        <td>PRIORITY1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>$('td:contains("PRIORITY1")').addClass("red");</script>
```

Since you do not have control of the HTML file or the serving routine, one of very few solutions would be to program a plug-in to Chrome and have Chrome color the lines :-)